# SVG logo - How to treat group of paths as copy-pastable character?

Tags: svg, figma

This group of paths (made using [figma](https://www.figma.com/)) renders as something representing the letter f

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="580" height="180" viewBox="0 0 580 180" fill="none">
    <g id="f" stroke="black" stroke-width="7.99608" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-linecap="round">
        <path id="f_body" d="M459 37.763C476.182 32.737 509.41 32.869 509.944 52.842C510.054 65.679 509.947 137.992 510 138" />
        <path id="f_line_bot" d="M469 142H531.332" />
        <path id="f_line_top" d="M469 70H531.332" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to make sure this "f" can be copy-pasted like a regular `<text>` element?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="580" height="180" viewBox="0 0 580 180" fill="none">
    <text x="10" y="40" font-family="Arial" font-size="24" fill="black">
        f
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Draw a transparent `<text>f</text>` approximately the same size and position above.

Comment: While there is a `<tspan>` element in svg to style single characters individually similar to HTML `<span>` – you can't insert any geometry elements in `<tspan>` (like `<path>`) So you need to use tricks like invisible text or you may also convert your custom svg glyphs to a font (via tools like icomoon or fontello)

Answer (score 0):

No, the `<path>` *represent* a letter F,
even Figma doesn't see an F.

Its you that can read it as an F.

You could write software

- that hunts down `id="f`" notatation,
- **parses all path** (this will take you same time)
- and create a textpath,

But doing it by hand for one alfabet is likely faster.

Comment: There's no simple way to wrap the <g> somehow insde a <text>
or the other way around?